# Getting Error while installing ClearCase plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, clearcase, eclipse-juno, clearcase-remote-client

I am installing IBM Clearcase plugin for Eclipse with following steps:

1. For Eclipse Juno >> Help > `Install New Software...`
2. click "`Add...`": http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows/"
3. Click "`OK`"
4. Select the available packages and click "`Finish`".

I am getting below error while installation :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Rational ClearCase MVFS Support 7.6.0.v201105111445 (com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh.feature.group 7.6.0.v201105111445)
Missing requirement: Rational ClearCase Refresh Provider For MVFS Support 7.6.0.v201105111445 (com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh 7.6.0.v201105111445) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.update.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Rational ClearCase MVFS Support 7.6.0.v201105111445 (com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh.feature.group 7.6.0.v201105111445)
To: com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh [7.6.0.v201105111445]
```

Where can I find the missing dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a CCRC installation with a recent (3.4+) Eclipse, you should follow [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21327758).

[image: ccrc installation]

The link you are using is to add ClearCase (as detailed in "[Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (For Eclipse), Version 7.6.0.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674)"), not CCRC, to Eclipse, and it won't work anyway, since you don't have ClearCase on your workstation.

**Warning**: See "[**System Requirements for the ClearCase Remote Client**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224586)".
It only reference Eclipse3.x, no Eclipse 4.x.
An [Eclipse Juno 4.2](http://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20120627_junorelease.php) might be too recent to support a CCRC plugin.

Comment: Ok. so what should I use if I want to integrate CCRC in Eclipse Juno ? so that I can use all CCRC commands from Eclise only

Comment: @RaG you should use what is detailed in the first link (click on "this technote") that I mention in my answer.

Comment: Any specific plugin you would want to suggest ?

Comment: @RaG just the one included in the technote I mention.

Comment: I m getting below Error :

The items selected for install include software (com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ide.feature.feature.jar) that requires install procedures from the older Eclipse Update Manager.  The installation cannot continue.

Comment: @RaG it is possible that the CCRC plugin isn't yet compatible with Eclipse 4.x, only 3.x: see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224586

Comment: Thats sad because I am using latest Eclipse juno 2 (Eclipse 3.9) and CCRC 7.1.2. I want to integrate both of them so I do not have to use two IDE one for checkin check out and another for development :(  ..... Any suggesstions ??

Comment: @RaG CCRC client is based own its eclipse (in a lower version) that you could use. Or you can use the most recent Eclipse you can find in the system requirement page, like Eclipse 3.7.x, but only if you have a CCRC 7.1.2.5 or later.

Comment: I m using CCRC 

Version: 7.1.2
Build id: 7.1.2.D100920


and ECLIPSE JUNO 

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: @RaG 7.1.2 means Eclipse 3.6 only. Any Eclipse more recent would need at least CCRC7.1.2.1 or later. And don't forget the version of the CCRC client is determined by the CCRC *server*: Your server need to be at least 7.1.2.x or later if you want a more recent version of a CCRC client.

Comment: my server version is 7.1.2

Comment: @RaG so an upgrade (of the CCRC server) would be necessary: 7.1.2.5 or later in order to use an Eclipse 3.7. But even then, it would *not* be compatible with a Juno 3.9.

Comment: so any other plugin, which can be used ?

Comment: @RaG not to my knowledge no. There is a sourceforge project for a ClearCase Eclipse plugin, but this is for a full ClearCase only, not CCRC.